# Reference classes across dynamic web projects on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, dynamic, web

I have two dynamic web projects - A & B.  Project B references classes in Project A.  Project A runs great on Tomcat locally.  Project B runs on Tomcat locally too, but when I run it referencing Project A classes on Tomcat, the classes from Project A are missing in Tomcat and thus throwing a class not found exception.

Since I cannot jar the Project A files, how can I get the classes from Project A to a local Tomcat deployment so that Project B can run when referencing Project A classes?

Comment: In a similar case (well, more two webapps using a non webapp project) I simply use ant to jar my shared project classes and include them in the webapp at build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If two web applications share some common classes then these classes should be refactored out of the web application code base and put into a separate library (jar file). This jar can then be added to your web applications as a dependency.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  But if one has a lot of classes, that can add up to a lot of time.  Is there anyway to do what the question asks though?  I am looking to save some time in the short term - long term i can refactor.  thanks

Comment: @AndroidAddict - refactoring classes our of the webapp into a common jar is not a big task. If you've got a half decent IDE then it should be a matter of minutes to do this.